# Salesforce Long Text Area

Tags: salesforce

This is a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find an answer. I have created a long text area in Salesforce and set the visible lines to 2:

[image]

But when viewing the field in a lead record - all rows are shown:

[image]

Referring to the documentation for the visible lines attribute:

> For long text area fields, set the number of lines to be displayed on edit pages.

So I can set the number of visible lines on the edit page no problem, but how do I set the number of visible lines for the text area long field on the lead details page?

Comment: Is this question related to programming in some way?

Comment: I was going to suggest using a formula field to show a substring of the long text area field, but it appears you can't use one in a formula.

Comment: I am not sure of the solution, but there may be a programmatic way of solving the problem. Otherwise you are probably right Robert and maybe this is better suited for the Salesforce discussion boards.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if this turns out to be the wrong place for this question is it possible to move it to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @DanielBallinger: SalesForce is not a valid migration path; it's still in beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you [can't use Text Area (Long) within formulas](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br4g) you could create a before insert/update trigger to copy a shortened value to another custom field that you only display on the view layout?

The approach might be a bit heavy handed and will also muck up the inline editing.

Comment: Thanks daniel - seems to be the only way.